# How do I integrate SURF algorithm with particle filter tracking?

Tags: opencv, svm, surf, object-detection, particle-filter

I'm new to the image processing field. I'm currently trying to detect multiple persons in a video using the SURF algorithm with SVM training for detection, and the particle filter for tracking. So far, I used the bag-of-features to build a vocabulary and cluster keypoints from a set of images (for both persons and nonpersons) and used two SVMs to classify if the test data are persons or not. Now that the classification is done, I'm planning to use the SURF keypoints extracted from the test data for the particle filter.

Basically, I want to justify the SURF keypoints to suit the particle filter input, feed these points into the particle filter algorithm, and then start tracking the targets and drawing circles representing the particles at the same time.

How do I do this? :( I'm trying to study the code provided here https://github.com/NewProggie/Particle-Filter but I kinda got lost because it AdaBoost, and of course, the particles are generated randomly. Thank you very much!

Comment: You should also try computing optical flow every frame, for each detection. Then once in a while, every 10th frame, try to find local patch that fits your model the best( if minimal error is less then some threshold stop tracking)

Comment: not much idea about multi tracking, but there is a kalman filter tutorial for multiple object tracking in youtube by "student dave".Check that once